# How to optionally import package in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

In standard JavaScript/Node.js you can do the following:

```
let myPackage;
try {
    myPackage = require("myPackage");
} catch (e) {
    console.log("myPackage has not been installed");
}

if (myPackage) {
    console.log("myPackage has been installed, using package...");
    // Use `myPackage` here
} else {
    // Fallback to `myPackage` alternative
}
```

However in TypeScript you primarily use [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statements.

How can I achieve the same concept with import statements in TypeScript and gracefully fail if the package is not installed?

Comment: I believe this has been answered in a different post.  Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444064/typescript-conditional-module-import-export/53809073

Comment: You can take a look at mPrinC's answer.